# Determine the square root of a number

Tags: java

I have the following lines of code from my homework, which takes some numbers. I am trying to figure what function is used to find the square root of a number. How does one do this?

```
 System.out.println("find the value of c if:");
 Scanner kbreader=new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("a="+" ");
 double a=kbreader.nextDouble();
 System.out.print("b=" + " ");
 double b=kbreader.nextDouble();
 System.out.print("c=" + " " );
 System.out.print((a*a)+(b*b));
```

Comment: Improve your google fu http://www.googleguide.com/advanced_operators_reference_print.html

Comment: sorry but  im only 2ndyr. not very familiar with this and not so talented to do some programs. LoL/ ;) where do i put the math.sqrt?

Comment: Yeah, but a lot of SO can be answered with simple google search. Half the point of SO is to have people end up HERE, with an answer.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What's wrong with [`Math.sqrt(double)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29)?

Comment: sorry but im only 2ndyr. not very familiar with this and not so talented to do some programs. LoL/ ;) where do i put the math.sqrt? thanks in advance :)

Comment: Pythagoras' formula right? `System.out.print(Math.sqrt((a*a)+(b*b)));` should work.

Comment: sorry for this lil' kind of Question. :) thanks to you. maybe my code before is not complete so it makes error everytime i command to run it.i use that code also but it not works maybe i forgot to put somethine ;). thanks  a lot again. God Bless ;)

Answer (score 5):

[Math.sqrt(double)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29)

If you're going to program much in Java you'll want to get familiar with the core libraries. The [Java Tutorials](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) is a good place to start.

Answer (score 3):

Look at the Math class:  http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand, what's wrong with the standard [sqrt](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29) function?

Answer (score 0):

[Math.sqrt(double)](http://download-llnw.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#sqrt%28double%29)

Answer (score -1):

Running code in JAVA without using predefined function

```
class sqrt{
    public static void main(String [] args){
        double n=9;
        double x=1;
        double a=n;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            x=0.5*(x+a/x);
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: It's very unclear what the code in this answer does. I don't think it a helpful answer for the original poster, who was clearly looking for a standard library method.